# How to parse special characters from JSON object in JScontroller of lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, rest-api, lightning, rest

Here is the received REST response(body):

```
{"meta":{"request":"/generic/searchResults","status":"SUCCESS","conversationId":"T4j2SVYPrCTTEmomDAYf","responseTime":34,"resultSize":4,"errors":[],"appMessages":[],"totalRecords":4,"pageNumber":1,"totalPages":1,"pageSize":25},"items":[{"attributes":[{"name":"id","value":"196-0"},{"name":"masterId","value":"154"},{"name":"tenantId","value":"7624"},{"name":"source","value":"S3_DIR"},{"name":"title","value":"KO1016536"},{"name":"accessURL","value":"/knowledge/s3/retrieve?path=knowledge/KO1016536en_GB.html"},{"name":"brandNames","value":"Hesston,Spracoupe"},{"name":"brandCodes","value":"SC,HS,C"},{"name":"causeCodes","value":"Information"},{"name":"categoryNames","value":"Application Equipment,Hay Equipment"},{"name":"subcategoryNames","value":"3000 Srs. Spra-Coupe,4000 Srs. Spra-Coupe,4600 Srs. Small Square Baler"},{"name":"models","value":"4655 Baler,SC3450,SC3650,SC4400,SC4455,SC4640,SC4655"},{"name":"contentType","value":"text/html"},{"name":"content","value":"Failure Sub-Category:\n \n     <b>Sales&#x2F;Marketing&#x2F;Product</b> Information\n \n     \n \n     \n \n     \n \n      \n \n     Created:\n \n     2012&#x2F;04&#x2F;18\n \n     Last Modified:\n \n     2014&#x2F;08&#x2F;08\n \n    \n \n    Problem\n\n    What"},{"name":"indexedTime","value":"1466150854216"},{"name":"_version_","value":"1537370598110396416"}],"facets":[],"facetRangeResponse":[],"resultSet":[],"panelSet":[]},{"attributes":[{"name":"id","value":"193-0"},{"name":"masterId","value":"154"},{"name":"tenantId","value":"7624"},{"name":"source","value":"S3_DIR"},{"name":"title","value":"KO1016467"},{"name":"accessURL","value":"/knowledge/s3/retrieve?path=knowledge/KO1016467en_GB.html"},{"name":"brandNames","value":"Challenger,Hesston,Massey Ferguson"},{"name":"brandCodes","value":"MF,CH,HS"},{"name":"causeCodes","value":"Attachment"},{"name":"categoryNames","value":"Hay Equipment"},{"name":"subcategoryNames","value":"4900 Srs. Large Rect Baler,Bale Accumulator"},{"name":"models","value":"4910,AC25,BA4"},{"name":"contentType","value":"text/html"},{"name":"content","value":"on a Hesston 4910 baler?\n \n    Symptom\n\n    Bale accumulator for a 2003 model year large square baler\n \n    Solution\n\n    In addition to the parts that come with the bale accumulator, <b>Wholegoods&#x2F;Sales</b> part"},{"name":"indexedTime","value":"1466150853155"},{"name":"_version_","value":"1537370596998905856"}],"facets":[],"facetRangeResponse":[],"resultSet":[],"panelSet":[]},{"attributes":[{"name":"id","value":"251-20"},{"name":"masterId","value":"154"},{"name":"tenantId","value":"7624"},{"name":"source","value":"S3_DIR"},{"name":"title","value":"KO1016467"},{"name":"accessURL","value":"/knowledge/s3/retrieve?path=knowledge/KOs-NewMetadata/KO1016467en_GB.html"},{"name":"brandNames","value":"Challenger,Hesston,Massey Ferguson"},{"name":"brandCodes","value":"MF,CH,HS"},{"name":"causeCodes","value":"Attachment"},{"name":"categoryNames","value":"Hay Equipment"},{"name":"subcategoryNames","value":"4900 Srs. Large Rect Baler,Bale Accumulator"},{"name":"models","value":"4910,AC25,BA4"},{"name":"contentType","value":"text/html"},{"name":"content","value":"accumulator for a 2003 model year large square baler\n\n            Solution\nIn addition to the parts that come with the bale accumulator, <b>Wholegoods&#x2F;Sales</b> part number MK41233 Hitch Adapter and MK41034 Valve Kit"},{"name":"indexedTime","value":"1466150868374"},{"name":"_version_","value":"1537370612956135424"}],"facets":[],"facetRangeResponse":[],"resultSet":[],"panelSet":[]},{"attributes":[{"name":"id","value":"251-79"},{"name":"masterId","value":"154"},{"name":"tenantId","value":"7624"},{"name":"source","value":"S3_DIR"},{"name":"title","value":"KO1016536"},{"name":"accessURL","value":"/knowledge/s3/retrieve?path=knowledge/KOs-NewMetadata/KO1016536en_GB.html"},{"name":"brandNames","value":"Hesston,Spracoupe"},{"name":"brandCodes","value":"SC,HS,C"},{"name":"causeCodes","value":"Information"},{"name":"categoryNames","value":"Application Equipment,Hay Equipment"},{"name":"subcategoryNames","value":"3000 Srs. Spra-Coupe,4000 Srs. Spra-Coupe,4600 Srs. Small Square Baler"},{"name":"models","value":"4655 Baler,SC3450,SC3650,SC4400,SC4455,SC4640,SC4655"},{"name":"contentType","value":"text/html"},{"name":"content","value":"Information\n\n                Global Failure Sub-Category:\n\n                <b>Sales&#x2F;Marketing&#x2F;Product</b> Information\n\n                \n\n                \n\n                \n\n                 \n\n                Created:"},{"name":"indexedTime","value":"1466150879168"},{"name":"_version_","value":"1537370624274464768"}],"facets":[],"facetRangeResponse":[],"resultSet":[],"panelSet":[]}],"rels":[]}
```

wanted output on parsing 
Created: 
2012/04/18
Last Modified:
2014/08/08

Comment: That's not JSON. Where are you getting this data from?

Comment: @sfdcfox earlier I have posted only part of the code. I'm receiving it from external system as a response to REST API call. I'm using getBody() function to retrieve the above-mentioned data from the response of REST call.

Comment: Using apex class I'm doing the REST call and passing part of the response to the lightning component controller as a JSON string.

Comment: I think you should encode your string in base64 with [EncodingUtil Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm) on the server side, and then decode it on the client side with something like [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)